# Where to find "Send As" and "Send On Behalf Of" mail settings in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

In searching the Microsoft Graph API documentation I have been unable to find any documentation on any APIs that would allow me to get the "Send as" or "Send on behalf of" settings for an Office 365 mail user.

I'd like to fetch these prior to sending an email so that my application can allow users to choose which emails to send from.

Anyone have any insight as to if this information is behind any of the v1.0/beta graph APIs or whether it is just completely unavailable.

Here's the documentation for how Microsoft informs users how to set up send-as aliases  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/add-users/give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user?redirectSourcePath=%252farticle%252fSend-email-from-another-user-s-mailbox-in-Office-365-2B828C5F-41AB-4904-97B9-3B63D8129C4E&view=o365-worldwide#bkmk_sendemailanotheruser

Comment: I am also looking for this feature. An equivalent on Google API would be this: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/list. Do you support this, Microsoft?

Answer (score -3):

You can find this under the [Send Outlook messages from another user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user) section of the documentation.

> Two types of permissions apply to sending messages from another user: [Microsoft Graph permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference), and mailbox permissions.

Comment: I have looked at that link, and nothing seems to address which API to use to find out the permission rules a certain user has. Could you be more specific?

Comment: This does not answer the question. Furthermore it's basically just a link. Please remove.